# Hillsong Website- Transitioning from one background image to the next smoothly whilst scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I would like to create a website, similar to this http://hillsong.com/
in the sense that scrolling down the page results in the writing/information scrolling up but then reveals a new background image which is different from the previous and is fixed.

How can I do that?
At the moment I've been searching on the web however I am new to coding and programming and I need a lot of help. This is what I've done so far: (Can someone please help me thanks)

how can I get the background affect?

Comment: This is called parallax scrolling effect, perhaps that would help in your searching.

Comment: @aarosil That's not what parallax scrolling is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and simple CSS only example I put together with this effect: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLwt4sqp/)

HTML

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div class="break">Break space</div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div class="break">Break space</div>

<div id="three"></div>
<div class="break">Break space</div>

<div id="four"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#one {
    background: #000 url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Sling-Sat_removing_space_debris.png') fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#two {
    background: #000 url('http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/96/51/spaceships-in-space-2_00449651.jpg') fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#two {
    background: #000 url('http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/96/51/spaceships-in-space-2_00449651.jpg') fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#three {
    background: #000 url('http://www.nss.org/tourism/SpaceShipTwo-1600.jpg') fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For more advanced parallax scrolling techniques, I would suggestion looking into some tutorials like:

https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641